# How to add and remove line spacing using PHP?

Tags: php

Everytime I submit the textarea it automatically adds line spacing at the top of the textarea box.  How and where to add coding that will only input new lines using the return key (enter)?

```
<div class="header"> 
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mycomments.php" method="POST"> 
<textarea input type="text" name="Comments" style="height:100%;width:100%"
cols="100%" rows="10" ><?php include 'comments.php';?></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: did you look at what's in `comments.php`? Just because THIS particular snippet of code doesn't have extra line breaks, doesn't mean the file you're including doesn't either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what exactly goes on inside `comments.php`, you'd have to do this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'comments.php';
$buffer = trim(ob_get_clean());
?>
<textarea input type="text" name="Comments" style="height:100%;width:100%"
cols="100%" rows="10" ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($buffer); ?></textarea>
```

The trim() function gets rid of whitespace from the beginning and end of strings.

Comment: @user2714558 great! Would you mind clicking the green checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted?